# instance_variable_set is not setting the right variable in an instance

Tags: ruby, unit-testing, instance-variables, minitest, class-instance-variables

I have an API endpoint I'm testing using Ruby. I have 8 tests that look like the following:

```
it "must rate limit on this api" do

  body = {
    ..
  }

  # Current limits assigned to this api endpoint are 5 requests every 5 minutes.
  # So this test will make 5 calls in short succession to trigger the rate limiter
  with_logging_suppressed do
    5.times do
      post '/api/endpoint/', body.to_json
      last_response.status.must_equal 200
    end

    post '/api/endpoint/', body.to_json
    last_response.status.must_equal 429
    last_response.body.include? "You are doing this too often"
  end
end
```

When you POST to `/api/endpoint/`, it spawns a `RateLimit` class which contains a `validate_rate?` method and it uses an instance variable of `@timestamp` which is an array of timestamps of when the API has been called.

```
RATE_LIMIT = RateLimit.new(5, 5.minutes)
post '/api/endpoint/' do
  if RATE_LIMIT.validate_rate?
    ...
  else
    throw Error
  end
end
```

`RateLimit` would contain the following `@timestamp` instance variable with the following sample of timestamps which `validate_rate?` would compare against.

```
@timestamp = [2018-04-16 19:17:48 -0400, 2018-04-16 19:17:49: -0400, 2018-04-16 19:17:58 -0400]
```

However, prior to each test run, I MUST clear out the `@timestamp` array or the array will contain timestamps from previous tests, which of course ruins the test results

So I attempted to try to set the `@timestamp` array to a new array prior to each test run in the form of a `before` block.

```
before do
  RateLimit.instance_variable_set(:@timestamp, [])
end
```

The issue I am currently running into right now is that because the `RateLimit` instance isn't specifically created in this test, when I call `post /api/endpoint/`, I cannot seem to set the `@timestamp` variable if this makes sense. It does set a `@timestamp` to `[]`, but it's not setting the specific instance that was created when I am running the actual test

I want to keep `@timestamp` private, so I do not want to create a method that lets me get or set this private variable, so my only choice seems to be `instance_variable_set`.

Comment: It seems like a bad design to depend on class instance variables like that, but even so, if that code runs it should assign. The question is, did it run at the right time?

Comment: I've ran a debugger in the `RateLimit` class to use `instance_variable_get` on `@timestamp`, and the results of the debugger in the test file vs the `RateLimit` class returns different results. The test file returns `[]` for `@timestamp` for any time I stop the debugger, while if I call the debugger in `RateLimit`, it would return the correct `@timestamp` object with timestamps inside. This is what leads me to think I'm not getting the right instance

Comment: Is `RateLimit` a model? Does it get reloaded between tests?

Comment: It's not a model

Comment: RateLimit.new.instance_variable_set(:@timestamp, []) should work as expected

Comment: @andriy-baran `RateLimit.new.instance_variable_set(:@timestamp, [])` does not work, it tells me I need to set the 2 inputs `RateLimit.new(..,..,..)`

Answer (score -1):

You should stub another method:

```
before do
  allow_any_instance_of(RateLimit).to receive(validate_rate?).and_return(true)
end
```

Then test `RateLimit.new` in separate test examples

Comment: Sorry but this does not answer my question at all.